# How to reuse and parameter a Kendo UI grid EditorTemplate (using ASP MVC)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I've created a DropDownList EditorTemplate for grid inline editing *successfully*. Now I would like to reuse this template in multiple columns (same grid), and/or in different views with different grids.

What I figured out so far is if I omit the 'Name' for the dropdownlist in the template then the template automatically binds to that column what refers to it in the grid (using `.EditorTemplateName(...)`). However there are other things what should be parameterized (explicit or implicit) firstly the dropdown datasource.

Q: Having many dropdown in one grid, how to parameterize the dropdown datasource to prevent copy and paste the DropDownListTemplate.cshtml zillon times?

Q: Generally how can I parameter this template when using in multiple columns, and multiple views?

The view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Enumeration>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.Locale).Width(200)
            .EditorTemplateName("DropDownListTemplate");
        // columns.Bound(e => e.OtherColumn).Width(200)
        //    .EditorTemplateName("DropDownListTemplate", ???);
```

...and the template called DropDownListTemplate.cshtml and placed in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates

```
@model string
@(Html.Kendo()
  .DropDownListFor(m => m)
  .BindTo(ViewBag.LocaleDropDownListDataSource) // <- Having many dropdown in one grid, how to parameterize this, without copy and paste the DropDownListTemplate.cshtml zillon times?
  //.OptionLabel("Select Locale")
  .DataValueField("Locale")
  .DataTextField("Value")
  //.Name("Locale") // Omitting this binds the template automatically to the referring column in the grid. Using a custom .Name, what is not a column name in the grid ruins the working
  )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you have to reinvent the wheel, Kendo already provide us `GridForeignKey` column to be used zillion times.

Template code

```
@model object

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)        
      .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
)
```

Implementation in Grid

```
columns.ForeignKey(col => col.DepartmentId, (IEnumerable) ViewBag.Departments, "Value", "Text").Title("Department");
```

[**Demo**](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/foreignkeycolumn)

Comment: Yeah it doesn't have to be a FK, you also can call it "a property which connected to your collection" or "column that need to be selected by dropdown". It doesn't have to be an ID, it can be a text string as long as it matches with collection value

Comment: OK, cool. The only thing is not clear for me where it refers to the template name? (I suppose the dropdown template resides in "anyname.cshtml")

Comment: The moment you set this `column.ForeignKey` it will refer to `GridForeignKey` template. You can find it in `~/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/GridForeignKey.cshtml`

Answer (score 2):

Dion's answer is indeed correct in aspect that in foreign key (and similar) situations there is an out of the box solution what he explained, so I marked it as answer.

Despite of this, the general question how to parameter and editor template still a practical question and needs to be answered. The `EditorViewData()` naming in the builder is pretty self-explaining. (well, after you found it... :-)

The view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Enumeration>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.AnyColumn).Width(200)
            .EditorTemplateName("ReusableTemplate")
            .EditorViewData(new {AnyParameterName = anyValue1, OtherParameterName = otherValue1});
        columns.Bound(e => e.OtherColumn).Width(200)
            .EditorTemplateName("ReusableTemplate")
            .EditorViewData(new {AnyParameterName = anyValue2, OtherParameterName = otherValue2});
```

...and the template called ReusableTemplate.cshtml and placed in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates

```
@model object

@{
    // Access the actual parameter values anywhere including the kendo helpers below (if any) via ViewData:
    var any = ViewData.AnyParameterName
    var other = ViewData.OtherParameterName
}

@(Html.Kendo()
  .AnyHelperYouWant_or_NoHelperAtAll
  )
```

For example:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Enumeration>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(e => e.AnyColumn).Width(200)
            .EditorTemplateName("ReusableTemplate")
            .EditorViewData(new {Name = "list1");
        columns.Bound(e => e.OtherColumn).Width(200)
            .EditorTemplateName("ReusableTemplate")
            .EditorViewData(new {Name = "list2"});
```

and use it:

```
@model object

@{
    // Access the actual parameter values:
    // Note: You can inline this variable if you want
    var name = ViewData.Name;
}


@(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m).BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[name])
```

Comment: In the EditorTemplate would you still use the .BindTo (say if it were a Dropdown)? If you provided a completed example pertaining to the question above I would upvote.

Comment: @Encription. Yes you could still use in any legal syntax construction. See added example.